# R: plot values same color

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a dataset. Some X-values have different Y-values.
Now I want to group all X-values in same color.
How do I do this?[It must look this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pra1W.jpg)

Comment: please include a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, there's a built in dataset called `mtcars`. Let's use its `cyl` column for the x-axis, and `mpg` for the y-axis. Some X-values have different Y-values. Now, what you're asking for is a scatterplot, but with all X-values that are the same X-value to be of the same color. Easy:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
     geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group all `x` values and to assign a different color for each of them just convert it to a factor and use it as color in ggplot `aes`. Here is an exemple:

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 3, 4),
               y=c(12, 15, 14, 14, 15, 17, 16, 4, 7))

ggplot(data=dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was searching for!